# The sum of a list cannot be placed in a file I am trying to write. What can be done?

Tags: python, list, file

I am having a lot of trouble with writing the totals to a new file. When I run this code, it gives me an error code like this:

```
line 115, in <module>
    OutputFile.write("The total amount of money you spent on food is $"+str(round(FoodTotal,2))+"." +'/n')
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I have tried surrounding the list with square brackets. I have also tried converting the sum of each list into a string, but I get the same result. What can I do?

```
#import file and read it, change the Expenses.txt name into the name of the file you wish to read
FileName=input("Please input the name of the file you wish to read and include the .txt! (Remember to place the file in the same folder as this python file): ")
Expense=open(FileName ,"r")
#create five lists which the data will be sorted into based on word after value
FoodList=[]
HousingList=[]
TransportationList=[]
EntertainmentList=[]
MiscList=[]
#create a short term list to sort the expenses into
print()
count=0
for line in Expense:
    str=line.split()
    print(str)
    count+=1
    if "Food" in str:
        FoodPrice=float(str[0])
        FoodList.append(FoodPrice)
    elif "Housing" in str:
        HousingPrice=float(str[0])
        HousingList.append(HousingPrice)
    elif "Transportation" in str:
        TransportationPrice=float(str[0])
        TransportationList.append(TransportationPrice)
    elif "Entertainment" in str:
        EntertainmentPrice=float(str[0])
        EntertainmentList.append(EntertainmentPrice)
    elif "Misc" in str:
        MiscPrice=float(str[0])
        MiscList.append(MiscPrice)
    else:
        print("The Text File Provided is not in the Correct Format")
        break
    str.clear()
    
print(FoodList)
print(HousingList)
print(TransportationList)
print(EntertainmentList)
print(MiscList)

#add all the expenses by category
FoodTotal=round(sum(FoodList),2)
print("The total amount of money you spent on food is $",round(FoodTotal,2)," .")

HousingTotal=sum(HousingList)
print("The total amount of money you spent on housing costs is $",round(HousingTotal,2)," .")
#HousingPrint=str("The total amount of money you spent on housing costs is $",round(HousingTotal,2))," .")


TransportationTotal=sum(TransportationList)
print("The total amount of money you spent on transportation is $",(round(TransportationTotal,2))," .")
#TransportationPrint=str("The total amount of money you spent on transportation is $",(round(TransportationTotal,2))," .")


EntertainmentTotal=sum(EntertainmentList)
print("The total amount of money you spent on entertainment is $",(round(EntertainmentTotal,2))," .")
#EntertainmentPrint=str("The total amount of money you spent on entertainment is $",(round(EntertainmentTotal,2))," .")


MiscTotal=sum(MiscList)
print("The total amount of money you spent on miscellaneous expenses is $",(round(MiscTotal,2))," .")
#MiscPrint=str("The total amount of money you spent on miscellaneous expenses is $",(round(MiscTotal,2))," .")


#add all of the expenses together for the total amount of money spent
TotalExpenses=FoodTotal+HousingTotal+TransportationTotal+EntertainmentTotal+MiscTotal
OutputName=FileName.replace(".txt","-Output.txt")
OutputFile=open(OutputName,"w")
OutputFile.write("The total amount of money you spent on food is $"+str(round(FoodTotal,2))+"." +'/n')
OutputFile.write(HousingPrint+'/n')
OutputFile.write(TransportationPrint+'/n')
OutputFile.write(EntertainmentPrint+'/n')
OutputFile.write(MiscPrint+'/n')
OutputFile.write(TotalString+'/n')
OutputFile.write(OutputString+'/n')


TotalString=str("There were ",count," expenses that totaled: $",round(TotalExpenses,2)," .")
OutputString=str("Output file: "+OutputName+" has been created.")

print("There were ",count," expenses that totaled: $",round(TotalExpenses,2)," .")
print("Output file: "+OutputName+" has been created.")

"""
output=open("OutputFile.txt","w")
output.write(line)
output.write("\n")
output.close()
"""
Expense.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You reassigned `str` here:

```
str=line.split()
```

Never name a variable `str`, `list`, or any other builtin name -- it will lead to confusing bugs exactly like this one!  Running a linter on your code will help you catch things like this.

For what it's worth, using `str` and `+` to compose a string is generally considered "unpythonic".  Using an f-string is easier:

```
OutputFile.write(f"The total amount of money you spent on food is ${round(FoodTotal,2)}.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the built-in `str` on `str=line.split()` change it  to something else. Also use `f strings` since you don't need to do the explicit type conversion:

```py
OutputFile.write(f"The total amount of money you spent on food is ${round(FoodTotal,2)}. \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`str=line.split()` is your issue. You shadowed the built-in name `str`, replacing it with a list, so lines like `str(round(FoodTotal,2))` thus would fail because `str` is not a function any longer.